# Reference which doesn't reference anywhere?

Tags: c++

Following code snippet:

```
int ia[3][4] = { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 };
int(&row)[4] = ia[1];
```

[image]

I can't get my head around why this particular code is valid. For my current understanding I don't have a rational explanation. Can someone help me out with that? My problem is with `&row` which doesn't seem to reference anywhere. My only explanation is that this has to be valid because its an initialisation.

I've got the following explanation from my book:

> .... **we define row as a reference to an array** of
>   four ints

Which array? The one we are about to initialise?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
 int ia[3][4] = { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 };
```

Is an array of 3 elements, each element is an array of 4 ints.

```
int(&row)[4] = ia[1];
```

Here the `int(&row)[4]` part declares a reference named row that can reference an array of 4 ints. the `= ia[1]` initializes it to reference the second element in the `ia` array, which is an array of 4 ints.

Comment: "Here the int(&row)[4] part declares a reference named row that can reference an array of 4 ints." - this means it just can but it doesn't? Or does it point to the array which is getting initalised?

Comment: @KingJulian It can and does, you initailize it (the `= ia[1]` part) to reference (or point to if you want, but the wording "point to" would normally be used with a pointer, not a reference) an array of 4 ints. Perhaps you need to read through e.g. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in).

Answer (score 6):

```
int ia[3][4] = { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 };
```

`ia` is an array of 3 arrays of 4 `int` each.

`ia[0]` is `{ 0, 1, 2, 3 }`.

`ia[1]` is `{ 4, 5, 6, 7 }`.

`ia[2]` is `{ 8, 9, 10, 11 }`.

I don't quite understand why you say we would be "about to initialize" it -- at this point, `ia` is completely initialized.

```
int(&row)[4] = ia[1];
```

[Spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) (start with the identifier...):

`row`

...is a...

`(&row)`

...reference...

`(&row)[4]`

...to an array of four...

`int(&row)[4]`

...`int`...

`= ia[1];`

...initialized by `ia[1]` (because you *have* to initialize a reference, no way around it).

So `row` is now a reference to `ia[1]`, which is of type "array of four `int`". That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 0):

(&row)[4] means that it can reference to an array of 4 elements and ia[1] is a row from the 2d array ia[][] that contains 4 elements, hence it works fine.